# Text area sticking out of form

Tags: html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I've searched everywhere and none of the solutions I've found didn't worked for me.
I just want my Textarea to have a little margin from left and right, so it fits nice inside that gray border. I'm only able to move it a little from left side, but can't change the right one.
This is how it looks:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZetCM.png)

And here is code for it:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="container mt-5 ">
  <form class="card card-color form-border" @submit.prevent="createNewTask">
    <div class="card-header px-3 mr-2">
      Add new Task
    </div>
    <div class="card-block">
      <textarea class="form-control pull-left" rows="3" cols="2" v-model="newTaskBody" placeholder="Create new task!"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer px-3">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary ml-2">Add task</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <p v-if="error" class="error mt-2 alert alert-danger"> {{ error }}</p>
</div>
```

Only o

```css
.form-border {
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #888
    }
```

I have only made one style for form border, rest of it is bootstrap4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks normal, nothing goes out of the container. The only change is adding a margin, textarea left and right `mx-2`, I also removed from the card-header `mr-2` because it added a margin in the header unnecessarily?

```css
.form-border {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #888
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container mt-5">
  <form class="card card-color form-border" @submit.prevent="createNewTask">
    <div class="card-header px-3">
      Add new Task
    </div>
    <div class="card-block mx-2">
      <textarea class="form-control pull-left" rows="3" cols="2" v-model="newTaskBody" placeholder="Create new task!"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer px-3">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary ml-2">Add task</button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <p v-if="error" class="error mt-2 alert alert-danger"> {{ error }}</p>
</div>
```